# Google map API v3 conflict with prototype.js in Magento

Tags: javascript, google-maps, magento, google-maps-api-3

I need to embed Google map API v3 in Magento 1.9:

```
<style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

But Nothing happen because Google map API v3 conflict with prototype.js:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

```
this.each(function(value, index) {
      results.push(iterator.call(context, value, index));
    });
    return results;
  }
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Why you marked as duplicate, Dr.Molle ?. I can't find the solution.

Comment: Did you read the duplicate? The 2 possible reasons  mentioned in the duplicate are:  **1.** the usage  of the experimental Maps-API(you use the experimental version) **2.** the usage of a old prototypejs-version( current version is 1.7.2 , you use the !!6 years old 1.6.0.3 )